# Is a 64-bit Laptop going to be a problem for "Metro" apps?

Tags: wpf, windows-8, xaml, metro, 64-bit

I'm looking at a sample Windows 8 C# "Metro" style app (bingPushpin). When I 2-click MainPage.xaml, it gives me, "Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms."

My Acer Aspire laptop is, indeed, 64-bit.

Is this going to continue to be a problem for me, or is there a workaround?

If the former, can anybody recommend a Windows 8 dev machine (laptop)?

Comment: This seems more like a problem with the configuration of your system then anything.  I highly doubt Microsoft would have limited this feature to only the x86 platform.

Comment: Yes, I answered this myself 8 hours before your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I see: once I select "x86" from the "Solution Platforms" combobox (so that I've got, from left to right, "Local Machine | Debug | x86" it works fine.